# Pythonic way of keeping track of a total changing based on an event result 0/1

Tags: python, algorithm

I am building something which keeps track of bets.
I have a sequence of prices like this:

```
prices = [Decimal('4.42'), Decimal('2.93'), Decimal('7.47'), Decimal('6.80'), Decimal('23.00'), Decimal('6.47'), Decimal('12.50'), Decimal('4.95'), Decimal('16.19'), Decimal('17.00'), Decimal('12.32'), Decimal('7.15'), Decimal('9.93'), Decimal('6.60'), Decimal('6.68'), Decimal('12.38'), Decimal('18.68'), Decimal('19.00'), Decimal('6.79'), Decimal('4.50'), Decimal('6.90'), Decimal('30.00'), Decimal('140.00'), Decimal('4.80'), Decimal('2.37'), Decimal('199.72'), Decimal('3.08'), Decimal('11.00'), Decimal('9.31'), Decimal('17.50'), Decimal('5.50'), Decimal('19.00'), Decimal('23.00'), Decimal('3.45'), Decimal('38.00'), Decimal('38.00'), Decimal('6.52'), Decimal('15.23'), Decimal('8.67'), Decimal('3.85'), Decimal('6.24'), Decimal('15.68'), Decimal('34.99'), Decimal('5.50'), Decimal('10.74'), Decimal('8.60'), Decimal('7.80'), Decimal('19.69'), Decimal('9.96'), Decimal('6.71'), Decimal('15.48'), Decimal('5.70'), Decimal('11.38'), Decimal('47.36'), Decimal('9.91'), Decimal('11.50'), Decimal('15.26'), Decimal('5.10'), Decimal('17.50'), Decimal('5.40'), Decimal('8.92'), Decimal('16.41'), Decimal('5.64'), Decimal('56.11'), Decimal('8.21'), Decimal('14.57'), Decimal('8.60'), Decimal('4.50'), Decimal('23.00'), Decimal('4.10'), Decimal('2.52'), Decimal('5.68'), Decimal('10.98'), Decimal('11.16'), Decimal('22.00'), Decimal('7.50'), Decimal('4.90'), Decimal('5.70'), Decimal('12.50'), Decimal('5.42'), Decimal('20.17'), Decimal('10.92'), Decimal('8.60'), Decimal('27.00'), Decimal('44.00'), Decimal('10.95'), Decimal('12.39'), Decimal('6.04'), Decimal('3.70'), Decimal('84.93'), Decimal('10.55'), Decimal('12.50'), Decimal('14.92'), Decimal('7.86'), Decimal('7.40'), Decimal('4.56'), Decimal('33.59'), Decimal('3.75'), Decimal('2.71'), Decimal('8.02'), Decimal('5.77'), Decimal('7.39'), Decimal('1.94'), Decimal('8.03'), Decimal('3.90'), Decimal('14.00'), Decimal('16.00'), Decimal('2.54'), Decimal('8.86'), Decimal('5.46'), Decimal('16.64'), Decimal('5.90'), Decimal('144.19'), Decimal('26.00'), Decimal('60.00'), Decimal('1.95'), Decimal('4.10'), Decimal('22.40'), Decimal('7.18'), Decimal('4.80'), Decimal('9.20'), Decimal('5.43'), Decimal('9.00'), Decimal('15.00'), Decimal('198.20'), Decimal('8.00'), Decimal('37.43'), Decimal('4.60'), Decimal('10.50'), Decimal('50.46'), Decimal('18.50'), Decimal('425.39'), Decimal('9.04'), Decimal('2.52'), Decimal('6.00'), Decimal('110.00'), Decimal('8.60'), Decimal('6.00'), Decimal('2.88'), Decimal('8.54'), Decimal('26.00'), Decimal('10.00'), Decimal('7.21'), Decimal('48.00'), Decimal('10.51'), Decimal('6.40'), Decimal('12.96'), Decimal('150.35'), Decimal('29.26'), Decimal('14.57'), Decimal('25.00'), Decimal('3.73'), Decimal('10.50'), Decimal('14.32'), Decimal('8.42'), Decimal('16.58'), Decimal('12.00'), Decimal('17.21')]
```

I also have a sequence of bits representing a win/loss. The indices correspond left to right in date order:

```
results = '01011000010011110000000111100010010000011000010000010010000100000001011000000001000001010000000100010110101100010001100000100100000000100010010000100000001000'

initial_balance = 500
```

I am looking to go through the prices sequence like this:

```
if results[current_index_in_prices] == 1 
 current_balance = 0.05*value*current balance 

else:
  # ie 0= loss 
   current_balance =- 0.05 *balance
```

keeping track of the balances as I go.

```
balance_list.append(current_balance)
```

I was wondering if there was a clever way of doing this in-memory as we go through the list rather than the method I have tried to sketch out.

Comment: You can avoid needing an explicit index by using `zip`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for bit, value in zip(results, prices):
    diff = 0.05 * value * current_balance
    if bit == '1':
        current_balance += diff
    else:
        current_balance -= diff
```

or if you prefer:

```
signs = {'0': -1, '1': 1}
for bit, value in zip(results, prices):
    current_value += signs[bit] * 0.05 * value * current_balance
```

Comment: prefer the first version because the 2 bit cases are quite distinct. In case of bit==1 need to increment by value*0.05 whereas if '0' then only the value is subtracted fro the current_balance

Answer (score 0):

You should employ `zip` as follows

```
initial_balance = 500
current_balance = initial_balance
for flag, price in zip(results, prices):
    diff = Decimal(0.05)*price*current_balance*(1 if int(flag) else -1)
    current_balance += diff
```

But you can make it more *functional* and hence less ugly and less buggy as follows,

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
g = (1 + Decimal(0.05)*price*(1 if int(flag) else -1) 
        for flag, price in zip(results, prices))
current_balance = initial_balance*reduce(mul, g)
```

The above code is **not** giving the correct result. There is something wrong with the increment logic. But the idea is to implement

```
x_ = x*(1 + r)**n
# in this case, the following
x_ = x*(1+r0)*(1+r2)...*(1+r157)
```

where `r` or `ri`s are rates for cumulative change.